# CSS Transitions on Android + iOS

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, webkit, transition

I have a tiny setup, two html files and one javascript installed (http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/).

The two html files have 100% height and width div's in them and one link (each link points back to the other html file to initiate the transition).

The script appears to create two divs when the initiation starts, d1 and d2, d1 is set to the current body content, and d2 is set to the target html files content. The CSS then transitions the two divs so a slide effect occurs and the finally the javascript takes the d2 content and sets it to the body content before getting rid of the two new divs.

The problem is that when the css transition starts, the font slightly changes (the characters get a little larger, when I say a little, I mean a tiny bit but noticeable). When the transition finishes, the font it back to normal. What this creates is a 'jumpy' feeling on the font, when the transition is initiated, you get this font jump and then it jumps back to its original size.

It happens on android a lot more than iOS.

I am running the app using Phonegap so I believe the web browser is webkit, Cordova.

Thanks for your help!!! I really hope somebody can help to fix this.

I have tried setting transition effects on the links to stop the font changing, like 3d settings and so on, my research showed a lot of people saying something about putting those items into the hardware layer so they dont get blurry.

Thanks!

Comment: It also seems to make some text bold and then after transition it seems to go back to normal

Comment: I've seen this happen on OSX, but that's because OSX renders text with sub pixel antialiasing very bold. Any transition effects temporarily disable the sub pixel text rendering, so the text "pops" back into bold after the effect is complete.  Usually the solution is to apply -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased.  However, iOS doesn't support sub pixel font smoothing and I kind of doubt that Android does either.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for that. Any idea what element I would apply that webkit styling to? Could I apply it for example to d1 and d2 *?

Comment: You can apply it to body if you like. I don't really think it will help but its worth a try.

Comment: Transitions in phonegap are very buggy, let alone third party plugins

Comment: Transitions are no "third party plugins". They are just CSS-properties.

Answer (score 0):

Transitions are a really bad thing in an android webview.

Some versions of android are creating some kind of sreenshot, animate the picture and than flip back to the real web-renderer.There is nothing you can do against this (If you find a solutiion, please add a comment or answer).

Sometimes it helps to set `preserve3d` or `translate(0,0)` onto the `divs`